# Clear Ajax form fields on submit

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

I have a form (for instant messaging) which in theory is working fine.

The form uses Ajax on submit to show messages - working fine.

The form however doesn't seem to be clearing the fields on submit, is there a way i can do this (clear text area only)?

Script below:

```
<div id='refresh'></div>
<form id='myForm'>
<input type='hidden' name='ConversationID'  value='<?php echo"$ConversationID";?>'>
<textarea name="Themessage" class="form-control content-group" rows="3" cols="1"></textarea>
<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-6"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6 text-right"><input name="submit" type="submit" id='btn1'  class="btn bg-primary" value="Send"></div>
</div></form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
setInterval(function() {
$.get("load_messages.php?id=<?php echo $ConversationID?>", function (result) {
$('#refresh').html(result);
});
}, 100);
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use setTimeout

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    getMessage();
});

function getMessage()
{
    $.get("load_messages.php?id=<?php echo $ConversationID?>", function (result) {
        $('#refresh').html(result);
        setTimeout(getMessage,3000);
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear textarea after show result in #refresh?

Put

```
$('textarea').val("");
```

After

```
$('#refresh').html(result);
```

Sorry if I didn't understand your question.